# WinRT: How do I set the hover over affect for a specific GridIViewtem?

Tags: winrt-xaml

I have a list of items bound to a GridView.  The list contains multiple types of data.  I use an ItemTemplateSelector to apply a DataTemplate to the different data types so they each have a unique look and feel.

I'm at a loss for how to remove the hover over effect of the GridViewItem in the DataTemplate for SubClass1 without DataTriggers.

```
public class Base
{
   public string Name {get;set;}
}
public class SubClass1 : Base
{
}
public class SubClass2 : Base
{
}
public PageViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
   public List<Base> ListOfBases {get;set;}
}


        <GridView
        x:Name="baseGridView"
        ItemsSource="{Binding ListOfBases}"
        ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource itemsTemplateSelector}"
        SelectionMode="Multiple"
        IsSwipeEnabled="false"
        IsItemClickEnabled="True"
        >

        <DataTemplate x:Key="SubClass1Template">
            <Grid Margin="0" Width="346" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" >
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Name}" />
            </Grid>
       </DataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to edit the VisualState styles of the GridViewItem. To do this right click on the GridView within within VisualStudio or Blend. Do this within the Design view or the Document outline. Select Edit Additional Template -> Edit Generated Item Container (ItemContainerStyle) -> Edit a Copy

If you want to remove it completely, the remove the elements within the PointerOver state

```
<VisualState x:Name="PointerOver"/>
```

You can use this to make any changes to it as well. Maybe you do not like the default hover color, but like another, here is where you would make those changes.

**UPDATE** Based on comment

To only have the hover style for a certain class, set the Visibility of the controls used for the hover style (eg: a border) to bind directly to the class. Then a ValueConverter would return Visible or Collapsed based on the type of the class

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't solve my problem.  I only want to remove PointerOver for a specific subset of items, not all of them.

Comment: Thanks Shawn.  Your suggestion will solve the problem.  I was hoping there was a way to use a DataTemplate or Style that I hadn't discovered yet.    I'll leave this topic open for a little while longer and see if someone has another solution, otherwise I'll accept yours.